# REACT - Dynamic JSX ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I was passed onto a question that was deemed a "duplicate", asked this question, and got told to ask a new question!  SO, I am trying to generate some JSX on the fly from a JSON document I parse.  This builds several type of forms with different UIs.

I just have a syntax error I can't fix!

CODE:

Changed since I first wrote this!

```
//--------
render() {

    const code = this.parse(this.props.form);
    console.log("-----------------------");
    console.log("code from parse()");
    console.log("-----------------------");
    console.log(code);
    return(
            <div>
                <h2>SmartForm Parser</h2>
                {code.map(function(op, index) {                     // loop through thr I-CODE STACK
                    const CodeIndex = `${op.component}`;            // fetch the OPERAND (COMPONENT)
                    let codeProps = {};                             // properties usually for start context
                    console.log(op);
                    if (op.context == startComponent) {             // and build the appropriate JSX code
                        return( <CodeIndex  /> );
                    } else if (op.context == middleComponent) {
                        return( <div> Hello MUDDLE </div>);
                    } else if (op.context == endComponent) {        //
                        return( </CodeIndex > );
                    } else {
                        alert('Malformed I code in code stack');    // something crook in the code stack
                    }
                  });
                }
            </div>
    );
}
```

And the error that is thrown up is

```
    + 1075 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/containers/smartForm.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (280:37)

  278 |                             return( <div> Hello MUDDLE </div>);
  279 |                         } else if (op.context == endComponent) {        //
> 280 |                             return( </CodeIndex > );
      |                                      ^
  281 |                         } else {
  282 |                             alert('Malformed I code in code stack');    // something crook in the code stack
  283 |                         }
```

Comment: Typo: `return( <CodeIndex /> );` instead

Comment: JSX elements are converted to function calls. `<Foo>{child}</Foo>` is the same as `React.createElement(Foo, null, child)`. You cannot "split" a function call over multiple statements. Think of the start and end tags as parenthesis of the function call. You have to restructure your code (and data) so that you can write the whole tag as a single expression.

Comment: @FelixKling..why null is there in React.createElement(Foo,null,child)....And is the sequence of passing parameters matters?

Comment: @MukulSharma: The second argument is the props (which there are none in my example). The third and any other following argument are the children. Yes, order matters.

Comment: @MukulSharma order is: `(element, props, children)` since no props are there so null.

Comment: Not sure why my question was marked down.  Care to elaborate markdownerer?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
return( <CodeIndex /> );
```

Instead of

```
return( </CodeIndex > );
```

Comment: I think the OP intends to render the component `<CodeIndex><div> Hello MUDDLE </div></CodeIndex>`.

Comment: That is spot on Felix.  In my operand stack, the operand can be a number of components.

Comment: The app I am buildin has 100+ forms, some of which may contain 100+ Fields.  I was trying to compartmentalise the for render... Much in the same way we have RenderInput, RenderSelect as functions that return correct JSX!  MY head hurts!  Thanks Felix.